# OpenLayers Circle Style Update During zoom

Tags: openlayers

I am using a stylefunction to dynamically draw an 'image' based on the feature geometry. The style function is dependent on the resolution (zoom level) so that the drawn items are a certain consistent real-world size. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/polygon-styles-vmep5) is an example of what I am doing. Is there a way to have the orange circles scale with the map during zoom (or at a minimum hide during zoom while other features remain).

Here is a code sample:

```
var styleFunction = (feature, resolution) => {
  return [
    new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: "blue",
        width: 3
      }),
      fill: new Fill({
        color: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)"
      })
    }),
    new Style({
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 500000 / resolution,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: "orange"
        })
      }),
      geometry: function(feature) {
        // return the coordinates of the first ring of the polygon
        var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
        return new MultiPoint(coordinates);
      }
    })
  ];
};
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288763/openlayers-3-style-function-for-dynamic-feature-font-setting/50292429#50292429 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827391/changing-the-icon-size-with-map-zooming

Comment: @JGH, those solutions are similar to what I have. While my style function is accurate before and after zoom, during zoom it does not update.

Comment: My assumption is I need to create a circle geometry instead of using a circle image. But this is a situation I foresee encountering in the future so i'm still curious if there's a solution.

Comment: The only candidates for circle images zoom animation would be `change:resolution` events, fired on view object several times during zoom. I tried it but they are being processed not very much in sync with actual animated zoom and are so useless for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return a collection of Circle geometries in the style function instead of a multipoint

```
var styleFunction = (feature, resolution) => {
  return [
    new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: "blue",
        width: 3
      }),
      fill: new Fill({
        color: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)"
      })
    }),
    new Style({
      fill: new Fill({
        color: "orange"
      }),
      geometry: function(feature) {
        // return the coordinates of the first ring of the polygon
        var geometries = [];
        feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0].slice(0,-1).forEach(function(coordinate){
          geometries.push(new Circle(coordinate, 500000));
        });
        return new GeometryCollection(geometries);
      }
    })
  ];
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/polygon-styles-qixiq

Note that the first and last coordinates of a linear ring are the same, you can ignore the last one to show 4 circles instead of 5 with 2 overlapping